# Dajaxice javascript core file not getting parsed

Tags: javascript, django, parsing, dajaxice

I've been looking everywhere for answer to my questions last few hours and couldn't find anything, so i decided to ask.

I followed installation instruction in docs of Dajaxice, got everything setup exacly the same, but unfortunetely my Dajax.core.js file is not getting parsed, so when i click on the javascript link in page html source it still contains template tags. I included the Dajaxice finder in staticfiles_finder(actually i ve got everything setup like in the ins instruction.

I am using django 1.4.1 develop server at the moment for testing and the latest Dajaxice version which is 0.9, is that make any difference ?

Does the order of vars in settings.py matters ?

What are the main reasons the Javascript files are not getting parsed, and actually when they should be parsed ?

Please help me as i really would love to use this app but just can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Community I thought you were a AI controlled bot. How are you making intelligent edits?

Comment: Ohh, you must be owning an anonymous edit. So the user was too lazy to sign up...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I advice you to check `STATICFILES_FINDERS` settings and other settings related to `django.contrib.staticfiles` app. Dajaxice uses a hook in this app to generate `dajaxice.core` file.

When you use debug server this static file is generated on the fly, on production environment the file will be generated when you run `collectstatic` command.

In your case it looks like the `dajaxice.core.js` file is founded by another static finder or served in any other way.

To check this please run the following command

```
python manage.py findstatic dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js
```

The output should look like

```
Found 'dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js' here:
  /tmp/tmp9nzeEd
```

*The filename in tmp dir will be different*

Also 2 pitfalls with collect static app:

1. When you update your `ajax.py` file to include new dajaxice views you have to run `collectstatic` again
2. The file is generated in `/tmp/` folder. So if you use `-l` key to generate links instead of copying files make sure that you will not remove this file by accident.

Comment: I'm running an Ubuntu 12.04 dev environment, dajax==0.9 and dajaxice=0.52. I'm having to manually copy the tempfile into a static directory, otherwise I just get 403 Forbidden errors when Apache tries to serve it. Is this some weirdness with my environment?

Comment: @ropable yes, perhaps your Apache is configured not to follow sym links or is forbidden to serve files from /tmp/ dir

Comment: i actually implemented my own ajax app , but this was helpful. Thanks